# Does Anyone know why my Docker image deployed through heroku is different than one created locally

Tags: node.js, docker, caching, heroku

I created a docker image locally and it runs fine. However when I push it to Heroku the container is different. Namely the .cache folder is missing.  Is there a limit to the size of Heroku docker containers?

Comment: There's some missing information here - how are you deploying your container to heroku? are you using the registry option or something else? How does your Dockerfile looks like? Where does the `.cache` folder come from locally?